# A refresh is needed to see the changes, using Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, refresh

Adding new data works fine for me, but I would like to see them immediately. For now I have to do a refresh. How could I achieve such effect? I'm using Laravel and Vue.

It has something to do with the push method, but I don't know what to do next

Here is my code:

```js
import JQuery from 'jquery'

let $ = JQuery
export default {
    data() {

        return {
            word: { 'title': '', 'second_title': '', 'status': '' },
            toggle: false,
            words: []
        }
    },
    created() {

        axios.get('./api/word')
            .then(response => this.words = response.data);
        Event.$on('taskCreated', (title, second_title) => {


            this.words.push(title);
            this.words.push(second_title);
        })
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    },
    directives: {
        focus: {
            inserted: function (el) {
                el.focus()
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        editWord() {

            $(".edit").toggle();
            $(".inner").toggle();

        },
        doneEdit(id) {
            var input = this.word;

            console.log(input)
            axios.patch('/api/word/' + id, input)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.word = { 'title': '', 'second_title': '', 'id': '', 'status': '' };
                    console.log("Success edit");
                })
        },

    }
}
```

Comment: Refresh the page or the in the vue-devtools?

Comment: Both the `axios` call and the `taskCreated` event method in `created` modify `words` in different ways - and both of these are asynchronous/happen out of step. Is this the source of your issues?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. I found useful resource, it should work, but I have problem with implementing it in my code. I'm posting link to the solution:

http://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/ (The best way: key-changing)

And to my bigger piece of code: https://pastebin.com/xxjZJ1kL

Please tell me how to implement it, because when I add this code:

```
<template>
  <component-to-re-render :key="componentKey" />
</template>
```

I'm losing visibility of some of the elements. I think i should name my component somehow, but I don't know what to do next.